# Cli-Config Helper -Multiple Entity Managers

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am using `Doctrine 2.5` with Slim 3. I got two Entity Managers Master and Slave.
In the Cli-Config.php file  when I am creating the helpers and passing the entity Managers and their connections as below,

```
$helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db'            => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($defaultEntityManager->getConnection()),
    'em'            => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($defaultEntityManager),
    'db_customer'   => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($customerEntityManager->getConnection()),
    'em_customer'   => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($customerEntityManager),
]);

return $helpers;
```

Now in the console when I try the command

```
php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

the schema relating to **`$defaultEntityManager`** EntityManager is only getting created the schema relating to **`$customerEntityManager`** Entity Manager is not created.

Any idea/suggestions which I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**doctrine `s cli script** expects **'em'** to be defined in the HelperSet returned. That will be used to create the schema.

You can see it [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php#L57)

To solve this, one way is to create 2 directories like:

- configA
- configB

and place 2 different **cli-config.php** scripts in each:

```
$helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db'            => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($defaultEntityManager->getConnection()),
    'em'            => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($defaultEntityManager),
]);
```

and

```
$helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db'   => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($customerEntityManager->getConnection()),
    'em'   => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($customerEntityManager),
]);
```

Finally, run:

```
php ../vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

from each directory

### Creating own script

Alternatively, you could create your own script based on [doctrine `s cli script](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.7/bin/doctrine.php), eg name it "doctrine.php":

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$commands = [];
$helper1 = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db'            => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($defaultEntityManager->getConnection()),
    'em'            => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($defaultEntityManager),
]);

$helper2 = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db'   => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($customerEntityManager->getConnection()),
    'em'   => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($customerEntityManager),
]);
```

ConsoleRunner::run($helper1, $commands);
   ConsoleRunner::run($helper2, $commands);

Place it on your project s root and run it as:

```
php doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

Comment: I get your point. In that case i will need to run the cli command twice for each updation of the database. Is there a way such that i create the the schema for both the database with just a single cli command.?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

$commands = [];

$emList = [
        $emFoo,
        $emBar,
        $emZoo
];

foreach ($emList as $em) {
    $acpApp = ConsoleRunner::createApplication(ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($em, $commands));
    $acpApp->setAutoExit(false);
    $acpApp->run();
}
```